# Invoking javascript in iframe from parent page - search box

Tags: javascript, invoke

I have 2 search boxes on parent page which I need to use to search on iframe search engine. So actually I have a search engine in iframe which looks really bad, as its build in php within an installation script its really hard to redesign in. I have created html header page which contain search boxes, as people will enter text inside the 2 boxes and push search I need to have results in iframe search engine.

Comment: You could post your form with target="iframeNAME" to access the _POST variables within the iframe

Comment: No sure what you want to do. Do you want to display the search results within the iFrame or on the parent page (and the iFrame should only do the search and direct the data to its parent)? Could you please add a sketch illustrating your setup? Is the iFrame under your control and running on your domain or subdomain?

Comment: The search engine is within the iFrame on the parent page, so results should load in iFrame within the parent page. I need to forward typed text from the 2 parent boxes to iframe (iFrame comes from the same domain), iFrame which isn't on the same page, but on the new page which will load after. The same when people push search will search in iframe. Its like you put one single thing on your site: a search box and, as people type text and push search will load a new page with Iframe insider with google results for that search.